# Is there way to specify compiler flags (e.g., preprocessor macro definitions) on the node-gyp command line?

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I'm trying to integrate a Node.js addon into an existing build system based on CMake.  The addon build requires a large number of preprocessor macro definitions and library dependencies that are available in the CMake context.  I would like to be able to pass these into `node-gyp` when it is invoked by CMake.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a simple way to do so.

I've tried using the approach used for plain old `gyp` like this:

```
node-gyp configure -d -DPOSIX=1
```

but the `-D` option doesn't seem to be passed on by `node-gyp`.  Looking at the source for `node-gyp`, this isn't entirely surprising.  Is there a straightforward, direct way to do this, or am I stuck with generating the entries in `binding.gyp` programmatically, pulling in this information from the environment or something else along those lines?

Answer (score 4):

Use "defines".

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "MyAddon",
      "sources": [ "File1.cpp", "File2.cpp" ],
      "libraries": [ "MyNeeded.lib" ],
      "defines": [ "_UNICODE", "UNICODE" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This adds the defines to the  in your config.gypi when running *node-gyp configure*

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked on this, but the issue here was that we wanted to use _different_ preprocessor definitions in certain build contexts (as determined by CMake), so simply adding them into the file wasn't really tenable (if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you see a downside to using the cflags setting in binding.gyp - but I just make something similar work by setting the flags using .bashrc

export CFLAGS='-m32'
export CXXFLAGS='-m32'
export LDFLAGS='-m3'

Comment: That would work for things that are handled as environment variables, but not for arbitrary preprocessor definitions.